# Debian не запускается после установки драйверов Nvidia

Tags: linux, debian, nvidia

Есть ноут с двумя карточками:

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [GeForce GT 520MX] (rev a1)`
.

Устанавливаю рекомендуемый самими Nvidia драйвер, и после перезапуска система не загружается. Пробовал заводить систему на разных версиях драйвера - нифига, всё по старому. Помогает лишь удаление оных через recovery mod. Всё перегуглил, ничего не помогает. Кто знает как быть в данной ситуации?

Comment: а какие сообщения в логах при загрузке системы были? Вообще, установка Nvidia на Linux -- мутная тема. Мне сложней было только с драйверами для wi-fi

Comment: посмотрите эту страницу https://wiki.debian.org/ru/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers

Comment: Драйвер снесите ну или что там в падает в dmesg почиатйте) да и есле не kernel panic то все у Вас загружается))) этож линух))))))) это 1) второе забудьте про этот драйвер)))